# Select limited columns from App Insights log data while transferring to storage account using Diagnostic settings

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, migrate, appinsights

I have configured a diagnostic setting in app insight to transfer telemetry data to storage account. I do not want to transfer/migrate user_authenticationId column from pageViews data. How can I prevent it from transferring to storage account using Diagnostic settings.

Comment: Hi @user2327358, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   Using **‘Diagnostic setting’**, `it is not possible to exclude columns from being exported through ‘pageViews’ category in application insights`. Rather, ***you can exclude the column ‘user_authenticationID’ with an application insights log filter query by executing the same on the ‘pageViews’ table and then save the query as a function to be executed at a time of your choosing or export the output of that query for a particular timestamp to an excel file or a storage account of your choosing***.

Please find the below application insights log query for excluding the column as stated above: -

[image: App Insights query results]

Also, find the below documentation link for more detailed information on **exporting the query results in a storage account and the requirements for the same**: -

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry**

Thus, in this way, you can achieve the desired.